# calculator and colortbl

Tags: tables

I want to make a table where the rowcolor is determined by a calculated number, see example below (which doesn't work):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=1.75cm,bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand{\myrowcolor}[1]{\ADD{#1}{400}{\ccsum}\rowcolor[wave]{\ccsum}}


\begin{document}
\huge
\ADD{200}{300}{\addresult}
\color[wave]{500} $200 + 300 = \addresult$\\
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
\pscircle*[linecolor={[wave]{\addresult}}](2,2){1}
\end{pspicture}\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
        \rowcolor[wave]{600}
        one&two\\
        \rowcolor[wave]{\addresult}
        \color{Red1}three&\color{Blue1}four\\
        \myrowcolor{50}
        five&six
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The problem is my homemade command `\myrowcolor`. I get the following error message:

```
misplaced \noalign
```

I have included some other lines just to demonstrate a couple of other combinations of color and calcucator that actually work.

Comment: `\rowcolor` must be the first instruction in a row, i.e. LaTeX chokes on your `\ADD` command!

Answer (score 2):

`\rowcolor` must be the first command on a row -- `\ADD` disturbs this rule and as such LaTeX ejects an error message.

Now there are two basic possibilities:

- Use a `\noalign` to cope around this `\ADD` problem, however, the result of `\ADD` is stored in `\ccsum`, a macro, which does not survive the `\noalign`, but this can be corrected with an `\xdef` (or `\GLOBALCOPY` from `calculator`) -- this will work for non-integer numbers as well.
- Shift the calculation into the argument of `\rowcolor[wave]{...}` with `\the\numexpr`, assuming that only integers are involved. -- this is the easier way!

Both methods are applied in the solution:

`\noalign` is a `TeX` primitive that allows actions to be done before the next row is started, this may include calculations etc.)

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}% Really???
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=1.75cm,bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\newcommand{\myrowcolor}[1]{\rowcolor[wave]{\the\numexpr#1+400}}

\newcommand{\otherrowcolor}[1]{\noalign{\ADD{#1}{400}{\ccsum}\GLOBALCOPY\ccsum\gccsum}\rowcolor[wave]{\gccsum}}

\begin{document}
\huge
\ADD{200}{300}{\addresult}
\color[wave]{500} $200 + 300 = \addresult$\\
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
\pscircle*[linecolor={[wave]{\addresult}}](2,2){1}
\end{pspicture}\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
  \rowcolor[wave]{600}
  one&two\\
  \rowcolor[wave]{\addresult}
  \color{Red1}three&\color{Blue1}four\\  
  \myrowcolor{50} five&six \\
  \otherrowcolor{-20} seven&eigth
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my, I have mispelled `eight` :D

Comment: Haven't you also misspelled misspelled? Mispelled doesn't look correct to me but I'm Danish so I might of course be wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, I just forgot `\\` - now it works!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}% Really???
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=1.75cm,bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\newcommand{\myrowcolor}[1]{\rowcolor[wave]{\the\numexpr#1+400}}

\newcommand{\otherrowcolor}[1]{\noalign{\ADD{#1}{400}{\ccsum}\GLOBALCOPY\ccsum\gccsum}\rowcolor[wave]{\gccsum}}
%\newcommand{\yetanotherrowcolor}[1]{\noalign{\MULTIPLY{#1}{4}{\mulresult}\DIVIDE{\mulresult}{3}{\divresult}\ADD{\divresult}{363}{\ccsum}\GLOBALCOPY\ccsum\gccsum}\rowcolor[wave]{\gccsum}}
\newcommand{\yetanotherrowcolor}[1]{\noalign{\MULTIPLY{#1}{4}{\mulresult}\DIVIDE{\mulresult}{3}{\divresult}\ADD{\divresult}{363}{\ccsum}\GLOBALCOPY\ccsum\gccsum}\rowcolor[wave]{\gccsum}}

\begin{document}
    \huge
    \ADD{200}{300}{\addresult}
    \color[wave]{500} $200 + 300 = \addresult$\\
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
    \pscircle*[linecolor={[wave]{\addresult}}](2,2){1}
    \end{pspicture}\\
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
        \rowcolor[wave]{600}
        one&two\\
        \rowcolor[wave]{\addresult}
        \color{Red1}three&\color{Blue1}four\\  
        \myrowcolor{50} five&six \\
        \otherrowcolor{-20} seven&eight\\
        \yetanotherrowcolor{80} nine&ten
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the usual way is to accept the answer that provided the help ;-)